# Every time I'm try to call the cloud function and it will through exception code "NOT_FOUND"

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

**Describe the bug**
I'm using the firebase new Updated Service https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/recognize-text. I'm trying to print the text data from the image but the exception through.
.
**To Reproduce**
Here is my kotlin code

```
package jp.co.camrininfotech.mlText

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.provider.Settings
import android.util.Base64
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctions
import com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException
import com.google.firebase.functions.ktx.functions
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.google.gson.*
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var functions: FirebaseFunctions
    private var myImageView: ImageView? = null
    private var myTextView: TextView? = null
    private var WRITE_STORAGE = 100
    private var SELECT_PHOTO = 102
    private val request = JsonObject()

    var photo: File? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        myTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        myImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        findViewById<View>(R.id.checkText).setOnClickListener(this)
        findViewById<View>(R.id.select_image).setOnClickListener(this)
        functions = Firebase.functions
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        if (view != null) {
            when (view.getId()) {
                R.id.checkText -> {
                    processImage()
                }
                R.id.select_image -> selectPicture()
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String?>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            WRITE_STORAGE ->
                if (grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    selectPicture()
                } else {
                    requestPermission(this, requestCode, R.string.permission_request)
                }
        }
    }

    private fun requestPermission(activity: Activity, requestCode: Int, msg: Int) {
        val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        alert.setMessage(msg)
        alert.setPositiveButton(
            android.R.string.ok
        ) { dialogInterface, i ->
            dialogInterface.dismiss()
            val permissonIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
            permissonIntent.data = Uri.parse("package:" + activity.packageName)
            activity.startActivityForResult(permissonIntent, requestCode)
        }
        alert.setNegativeButton(
            android.R.string.cancel
        ) { dialogInterface, i -> dialogInterface.dismiss() }
        alert.setCancelable(false)
        alert.show()
    }

    private fun selectPicture() {
        photo = createTempFile(photo)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        val dataUri = data!!.data
        var bitmap: Bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, dataUri)
        // Scale down bitmap size
        bitmap = scaleBitmapDown(bitmap, 640)
        myImageView!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        convertIntoBase(bitmap)


    }

    private fun scaleBitmapDown(bitmap: Bitmap, maxDimension: Int): Bitmap {
        val originalWidth = bitmap.width
        val originalHeight = bitmap.height
        var resizedWidth = maxDimension
        var resizedHeight = maxDimension
        if (originalHeight > originalWidth) {
            resizedHeight = maxDimension
            resizedWidth =
                (resizedHeight * originalWidth.toFloat() / originalHeight.toFloat()).toInt()
        } else if (originalWidth > originalHeight) {
            resizedWidth = maxDimension
            resizedHeight =
                (resizedWidth * originalHeight.toFloat() / originalWidth.toFloat()).toInt()
        } else if (originalHeight == originalWidth) {
            resizedHeight = maxDimension
            resizedWidth = maxDimension
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, resizedWidth, resizedHeight, false)
    }

    private fun convertIntoBase(bitmap: Bitmap) {
        val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
        val imageBytes: ByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
        val base64encoded = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP)
        requestJsonToCloud(base64encoded)
    }

    private fun requestJsonToCloud(base64encoded: String) {


        val image = JsonObject()
        image.add("content", JsonPrimitive(base64encoded))
        request.add("image", image)
        val feature = JsonObject()
        feature.add("type", JsonPrimitive("TEXT_DETECTION"))
        val features = JsonArray()
        features.add(feature)
        request.add("features", features)
        val imageContext = JsonObject()
        val languageHints = JsonArray()
        languageHints.add("en")
        imageContext.add("languageHints", languageHints)
        request.add("imageContext", imageContext)


    }

    private fun processImage() {
        annotateImage(request.toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                    val e = task.exception
                    if (e is FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                        val code = e.code
                        val details = e.details
                        Log.w("exception code ", "$code")
                        Log.w("exception details", "$details")

                    }
                    showSnackbar("An error occurred.")
                } else {
                    val annotation =
                        task.result!!.asJsonArray[0].asJsonObject["fullTextAnnotation"].asJsonObject
                    System.out.format("%nComplete annotation:")
                    System.out.format("%n%s", annotation["text"].asString)

                }

            }

    }

    private fun showSnackbar(message: String) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    private fun createTempFile(fileClass: File?): File {
        var file = fileClass
        val directory =
            File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/jp.co.camrininfotech.mlText")
        if (!directory.exists() || !directory.isDirectory) {
            directory.mkdirs()
        }
        if (file == null) {
            file = File(directory, "orig.jpg")
        }
        return file
    }


    private fun annotateImage(requestJson: String): Task<JsonElement> {
        return functions
            .getHttpsCallable("annotateImage")
            .call(requestJson)
            .continueWith { task ->
                println("annotateImage result " + task.result.toString())
                val result = task.result?.data
                JsonParser.parseString(Gson().toJson(result))
            }
    }


    private fun checkPermission(requestCode: Int) {
        when (requestCode) {
            WRITE_STORAGE -> {
                val hasWriteExternalStoragePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                )

                if (hasWriteExternalStoragePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    selectPicture()
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                        requestCode
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm using these dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
```

**Expected behavior**

Print the Text from the image

**Additional context**

W/exception code: NOT_FOUND W/exception details: null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for this issue. I'm not uploaded the **vision-annotate-images** in my firebase cloud function.

```
To deploy the function:

    Clone or download the functions-samples repo and change to the vision-annotate-image directory:

git clone https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples
cd vision-annotate-image

Install dependencies:

cd functions
npm install
cd ..

If you don't have the Firebase CLI, install it.
Initialize a Firebase project in the vision-annotate-image directory. When prompted, select your project in the list.

firebase init

Deploy the function:

firebase deploy --only functions:annotateImage
```

Comment: I can not find the vision-annotate-image directory in the https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples do you know where I can find it ?